# Is there a package for abbreviations management?

Tags: tables, macros, packages

I wonder if there is a way to efficiently manage abbreviations. When I do my Ph.D. work, I usually copy the contents from one document to the other. When rewriting contents to a journal or for a presentation, it is time-consuming to keep tracking the abbreviations and see whether they are defined or consistent. Also, adding a table of abbreviation can take a long time at the end of a large project or report. As a result, I think it is good idea to develop a package to manage abbreviations with functionalities as follows

1. Define abbreviations with a command like `\declareabbreviation{<abbreviation tag>}{<full abbreviated name>}{<text to typeset (the abbreviation itself)>}` and `\abbreviaton{<abbreviation tag>}`. The package then uses the command `\abbreviation` to typeset the abbreviation according to certain rules in the options. For instance, all abbreviations should be capitals regardless of how they were declared
2. By default, when the abbreviation is introduced in the text for the first time, the package typesets the full name of the abbreviation followed by the abbreviation itself between brackets. It could also be specified that the full name is printed in caps or, say, bold caps for first letters regardless of how the full name is declared
3. Highlight all abbreviations in the text or change their color. This could improve the ability of the author to (at a glance) see where the abbreviation is introduced for the first time and whether that location is good or not. It also helps see how frequently it is mentioned in the text
4. Replace all abbreviations (i.e., all instances of `\abbreviations{<abbreviation tag>}`) with their full name instead
5. Add an automatically generated table to the document showing the full name of each abbreviation and even the page where it was first mentioned in the text. This would be even better if it was compatible with hyper links
6. For common abbreviations such as PhD, it could be nice to set an option allowing the package to automatically add dots (i.e., Ph.D.) or remove them regardless of how the abbreviation name is provided when it was declared
7. Generate warnings when an `abbreviation tag` is used when it has not been defined. Also, replace the text with something like **??** for undefined abbreviation tags

Comment: Have a look at the [`acronym`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acronym) package.

Comment: Or at [glossaries](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).

Comment: https://ctan.org/topic/acronym